# jQuery: click to scroll to next section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function set up whereby when you click `.section-down-arrow-wrap` it will traverse up the ancestors and find the closest `.fullscreen` element, the idea is when you click this it will scroll the `.section` element down to the next instance of `.fullscreen` as you can see if this fiddle though: https://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/d9zbw1k2/ it isn't working as expected, some scroll you to the next one, some don't, some scroll you upwards. I need a method too that'll find `fullscreen` further up the tree as it won't always be the grandparent element of `section-down-arrow-wrap`. Here's the markup:
HTML:

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="fullscreen"> <span>
        <div class="section-down-arrow-wrap scroller">CLICK</div>
    </span>

    </div>
    <div class="fullscreen">
        <div class="half-screen">
            <div class="section-down-arrow-wrap scroller">CLICK</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fullscreen"> <span>
        <div class="section-down-arrow-wrap scroller">CLICK</div>
    </span>

    </div>
    <div class="fullscreen">
        <div class="half-screen">
            <div class="section-down-arrow-wrap scroller">CLICK</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.section-down-arrow-wrap.scroller').on('click', function () {

        var fuller = $(this).closest('.fullscreen').next('.fullscreen'),
            section = $(this).closest('.section');

        section.animate({
            scrollTop: fuller.offset().top + 0
        }, 700);

    });

});
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include the current vertical position of the scroll in your calculation [**`.scrollTop()`**](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

```
$('.scroller').click(function(){
    var fuller = $(this).closest('.fullscreen').next(),
        section = $(this).closest('.section');

    section.animate({
        scrollTop: section.scrollTop() + fuller.offset().top
    }, 700);
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8g7p31gk/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `$(section).scrollTop() +  fuller.offset().top` for this.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.section-down-arrow-wrap.scroller').on('click', function () {
        var fuller = $(this).closest('.fullscreen').next('.fullscreen'),
            section = $(this).closest('.section');
        section.animate({
            scrollTop: $(section).scrollTop() + fuller.offset().top + 0
        }, 700);
    });
});
```

```css
.section {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.fullscreen {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background: orange;
}
.fullscreen:nth-child(even) {
    background: blue;
}
.section-down-arrow-wrap {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
    <div class="fullscreen"> <span>
        <div class="section-down-arrow-wrap scroller">CLICK</div>
    </span>

    </div>
    <div class="fullscreen">
        <div class="half-screen">
            <div class="section-down-arrow-wrap scroller">CLICK</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fullscreen"> 
        <span>
            <div class="section-down-arrow-wrap scroller">CLICK</div>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="fullscreen">
        <div class="half-screen">
            <div class="section-down-arrow-wrap scroller">CLICK</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#scroll").offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

## button is a id where to click on

## scroll is where is is scrolling to

Comment: This scrolls to the set element, not to the 'next' section.